# Would dual-booting Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows 7 work succesfully on a Sony VAIO e series laptop?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, vaio, compatibility

Can anyone please tell me if the Sony Vaio E series or any other series (T or S) would work fine with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 in a dual-boot configuration?

I am planning to buy a SONY VAIO E series with following specs:

- 14'' Premium E series Sony Vaio laptop ( SVE14A15FDS or SVE14A15FDB)
- 3rd gen Intel® Core™ i5-3210M processor (2.50GHz / 3.10GHz),
- Intel® HD Graphics 4000
- Installed Memory : 6GB (4GB x 1 + 2GB x 1)
- Memory Type/Speed : DDR3 SDRAM, PC3-10600 1333 MHz
- Storage

  - Storage Capacity : 750 GB2
  - Storage Technology : Serial ATA
  - Storage Type : HDD 5400 rpm
- Wireless:

  - Bluetooth® Technology : Bluetooth® standard Ver. 4.0 + HS
  - Ethernet Protocol : 1000BASE-T/100BASE-TX/10BASE-T
  - WiDi Ready : Intel® Wireless Display Technology
  - WiFi Adapter : WiFi Adapter : Intel® Centrino® Wireless-N 2230 (802.11b/g/n)

Please tell me if the above or any other configurations would work successfully with dual-boot with Sony VAIO 2012 laptops.

Any comments/suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: Yes, of course it's going to work. Your laptop is powerfull, so go ahead!

Answer (score 3):

You can get a feel of how Ubuntu looks like on your system by booting it using Ubuntu [live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) or a [Bootable USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/) drive, without making any change to your current Operating System. You can fiddle around with the OS and check if all or most of the drivers are detected correctly. In some cases it is possible that some drivers may not be available but there are work around which may not be very easy to follow for a new user to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

It will work perfectly on your new LAP. Not only Windows 7 & Ubuntu. You can have any number of Operating System if you have Disk space. And Sony VAIO e series is good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Works good but you'll have issues with the Intel 2230 WIFI adapter.
I have an HP Pavillion DV7-7015CA running Ubuntu 12.04 and searching for a fix with NDISWrapper

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought one of these with **Windows 8** pre-installed, although this should work for all versions of windows. After reducing the size of the Windows partition in Windows and shutting down, I was able to boot from the LiveCD and install Ubuntu 12.04. To do this:

- Boot using <kbd>Assist</kbd>
- Press <kbd>F11</kbd>
- Select "Install Ubuntu" and follow the on-screen instructions.

I was unable to boot into Grub (ubuntu bootloader) straight away, after installing ubuntu, so I had to re-boot from the LiveCD (using the method above) and selecting the "Try ubuntu" option and move the grubx64.efi file to the Boot folder and rename it to bootx64.efi (after renaming the old one as bootx64.efi.old). This is done as follows...

Boot to live cd, open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda3 /mnt
sudo mv /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.old
sudo cp /mnt/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
```

After typing this and shutting down the machine, it let me boot into the normal grub bootloader, where you can choose to boot from Ubuntu or Windows.

If you recieve a **Secure Boot** message when booting from the LiveCD:
 - Turn the laptop off
 - Reboot using <kbd>Assist</kbd>
 - Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to go to the Bios.
 - Find the Secure Boot option in the "Security" menu, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then select the "Disable" option and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
 - Press <kbd>F4</kbd> to save changes and exit the Bios.

**NOTE:** You're unable to re-enable the secure boot option. (I just tried and it booted into Windows.)