# Boot directly from grub2

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm having some issues with the boot on my laptop. I have partitioned my HD, and installed Windows 8 first and Ubuntu 12.10 then, both for 64 bits versions.

The problem is, when I boot, the boot loader is the one of microsoft, and I want it to go directly to the grub2.

I've customized the grub2 and set it as the default, but it still boots from the microsoft boot loader.

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: What laptop is it?

Comment: This may help http://askubuntu.com/a/244490/62364

Answer (score -1):

You have more than one  right?
Check the boot order in your Bios and select Linux storage as primary. If this does not work reinstall the Linux, it will repopulate the grub and should be fine.

Comment: More than one **what** (HDD, boot loader)? As I read the question (I could be wrong) he installed both OS in the same HDD. So changing the boot order won't work.

Comment: thats right, that doesnt work.

Comment: My laptop is a HP Pavilion Dv6955 64 bits.